# Segmentation Fault 11 in Swift Program

Tags: ios, swift

I keep getting this error everytime I try to compile my assignment

```
(unresolved_dot_expr type='@lvalue [Book]' location=/Users/BandManFabo/Desktop/Lab03/Lab03/Bookstore.swift:18:9 range=[/Users/BandManFabo/Desktop/Lab03/Lab03/Bookstore.swift:18:9 - line:18:9] field 'books' function_ref=unapplied
```

I am using a class called Book which is somewhat of a model for books in a Bookstore which is another class. Book.swift is below

```
import Foundation

class Book {
    private var title:String
    private var numOfPages:Int
    private var price: Double
    private var quantity: Int

    init(title:String,pages:Int,price:Double,quantity:Int) {
        self.title = title
        self.numOfPages = pages
        self.price = price
        self.quantity = quantity
    }
    public func getTitle() -> String {
        return self.title
    }
    public func getPrice() -> Double {
        return self.price
    }
    public func getQuantity() -> Int {
        return self.quantity
    }
    public func toString() -> String {
        return "Title: \(self.title)\nNumber Of Pages: \(self.numOfPages)\nPrice: \(self.price)\nQuantity: \(self.quantity)"
    }
    public func subtractQuantity(amount: Int){
        self.quantity = getQuantity() - amount
    }
    public func addQuantity(amount: Int){
        self.quantity = getQuantity() + amount

    }
}
```

Bookstore uses this class to run

```
import Foundation

class Bookstore {
    private var totalbooks:Int
    private var gross: Double
    private static let MAXNUMOFBOOKS:Int = 1000
    private var books: [Book]
    //empty constructor for the bookstore
    init() {
        books = [Book](repeatElement(Book, count: Bookstore.MAXNUMOFBOOKS))
        totalbooks = 0
        gross = 0.0
    }

   /* Adds a new book to this bookstore.
   * @param b the book to add
   */
    public func addBook(b:Book){
        if Bookstore.MAXNUMOFBOOKS < books.count{
            books.append(b)
            totalbooks = totalbooks+1
        }else{
             print("\nBookStore: I cannot add a new book into stock.")
        }
    }

    /**
     * Adds a certain quantity of a book already in stock.
     *
     * @param title the title of the the book
     * @param quantity amount of copies to add
     */
    public func addBookQuantity(title:String , quantity:Int){
         // Search for the book...if found adjust the quantity,
        // otherwise, inform the user that the book is not available
        for currentBook in books {
            if currentBook.getTitle() == title{
                currentBook.addQuantity(amount: quantity)
                return
            }//end of if
        }//end of for
        // Book is not found in the bookstore
print("\nBookStore: I cannot increment the quantity of the book titled");
  print("'\(title)' because it is not available in the bookstore.");
    }// addBookQuantity

    /**
     * Checks if at least a certain number of copies of a particular book are in
     * stock. Note: You can use this method to check if a book is already in the
     * bookstore. This way, you won't create duplicate records of the same book.
     *
     * @param title the title of the book to search for
     * @param quantity the desired number of copies
     * @return
     * @returns true if title exists with specified quantity; otherwise false
     */
    public func inStock(title:String, quantity:Int) -> Bool {
        // Search for the book...if found, adjust the quantity.
        // otherwise, Book not in the BookStore.
        for currentBook in books {
            if currentBook.getTitle() == title{
                if quantity <= currentBook.getQuantity(){
                    return true
                }else{
                    return false
                }
            }//end of if
        }//end of for
        //Book not present
        return false
    }

    /**
     * Sells a particular number of copies of a certain book. If successful
     * (i.e. enough books are in stock to sell), the quantity of the book is
     * adjusted. Otherwise, no books are sold.
     *
     * @param title the title of the book to sell
     * @param quantity the amount of books to sell
     * @return
     * @returns true if successful; otherwise false
     */
    public func sellBook(title:String, quantity:Int) -> Bool {
        var sellCheck: Bool = false
        //will check to see if the books are instock
        let retval:Bool = inStock(title: title, quantity: quantity)
        //will do some operation if it is instock
        if retval {
            for currentBook in books {
                if !sellCheck{
                    if currentBook.getTitle() == title{
                        currentBook.subtractQuantity(amount: quantity)
                        gross = gross + currentBook.getPrice() * Double(quantity)
                        sellCheck = true
                    }//end of most inner if
                }//end of inner if
            }//end of outer for
        }//end of outer if
        return retval
    }

    /**
     * Lists information about each book in the bookstore
     */
    public func listBooks(){
        print("\nAll Books In Store and Info\n===============")
        for currentBook in books {
            print(currentBook.toString())
        }
    }
    /**
     * Lists the titles of all the books in the bookstore
     */
    public func listTitles(){
        // List all books titles
        print("\nTitles of Books\n===============")
        for currentBook in books {
            print(currentBook.getTitle())
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the gross income of this bookstore.
     *
     * @return
     * @returns gross income
     */
    public func getIncome() -> Double {
        return gross
    }

}
```

Not entirely sure where the segmentation fault is coming from. I appreciate any help

Comment: what are you trying to do here?
books = [Book](repeatElement(Book, count: Bookstore.MAXNUMOFBOOKS))

Comment: create an array of 1000 book objects

Comment: @RikeshSubedi Well spotted. OP, your code is wrong twice. `Book` is a class, not a book instance. Plus, if you change it to `Book()`, it will still be wrong because you'll get multiple references to the same instance.

Comment: okay so what should I change it to? @matt

Comment: @matt `Book()` will even cause a compiler error.

Comment: @vadian that was shorthand

Comment: use [Book]() instead

Comment: okay that is what I had at first

Comment: There's no reason to have methods like `getTitle`, `getPrice`, etc. This isn't java. Just use `public private(set) let title = ...`

Comment: im just implementing what my teacher has @Alexander

Comment: im not sure how strict he is going to be so I will just leave it like that

Comment: @RonBaker Then tell him to stop teaching his students this. It's not accepted practice in Swift. It's redundant, doesn't do what it does in Java, and just adds extra lines of code for no reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your init method in BookStore class

```
init() {
        books = [Book]() //empty list
        totalbooks = 0
        gross = 0.0
}
```

Comment: okay that is what I did. My teacher has us doing this java code in swift. Thought I might've been the wrong one

Comment: @RonBaker Better yet, just change these assignments into static initializations. `public private(set) var books = [Book]()`

Comment: Im not sure how strict he will be so Im just going to leave it like that